# Delete object for a nested array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

Based on an object like this:

```
var p = [
           {x: [
                 {x1: 1}, 
               ]
           },
           {x: [
                 {x1: 2},
               ]
           }
        ];
```

I need to filter `p` objects when x1 is different from 1:

```
var p = [
           {x: [
                 {x1: 2},
               ]
           }
        ];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var p = [
           {x: [
                 {x1: 1}, 
               ]
           },
           {x: [
                 {x1: 2},
               ]
           }
        ];

const results = p.filter(val => !val.x.some(v => v.x1 === 1));

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Would you mind adding a response for `strings` values? It would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What sort of string response?

Comment: I mean how can I use a different method than `some`. In some case that uses strings instead of `1` and `2` or any number.

Comment: I just post that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62869085/filter-object-for-a-nested-array-javascript