# Filter object for a nested array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Based on an object like this:

```
var p = [
           {x: [
                 {x1: "John"}, 
               ]
           },
           {x: [
                 {x1: "Louis"},
               ]
           }
        ];
```

I need to filter `p` objects when x1 is different from any of those values:

```
var p = [
           {x: [
                 {x1: "Louis"}, 
               ]
           },
        ];
```

Thanks all of you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is exactly the same as your question with the numbers.

```js
var p = [
           {x: [
                 {x1: 'John'}, 
               ]
           },
           {x: [
                 {x1: 'Louis'},
               ]
           }
        ];

const results = p.filter(val => !val.x.some(v => v.x1 === 'John'));

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` method and destructuring. Check for condition in filter method.

```js
var p = [{ x: [{ x1: "John" }] }, { x: [{ x1: "Louis" }] }];

const filter = (arr, item) => arr.filter(({ x: [{ x1 }] }) => x1 !== item);

console.log(filter(p, "John"));
console.log(filter(p, "Louis"));
```

Comment: Excellent. This is a very nice solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This will only work if x1 only has a single item in the array.

Comment: @AdrianBrand, You mean to `x` only has a single item right? Yes. you are right. It will work only for given data format. Thanks.